# Programs prints a space after new line "\n"

Tags: python

Hi I'm very new to Python, so this may be a really easy question.

I'm trying to print an user's home address. I need the zip code to start in a new line, however, when I add \n the program is printing a space.

Below is my code and a screenshot of my output:

```
print(420, "Marshall Street","\nCity, State\n",12345)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6jrN.png)

Please if someone could help me I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the argument `sep` like this `sep = "\n"`.

```
print(420, "Marshall Street","City, State",12345, sep = "\n")
```